# Determinant and symmetric power

Tags: rt.representation-theory, determinants, linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over some field $k$ and $T \in \mathrm{GL}(V)$. Then, we can view $T\in \mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{Sym}^k(V))$ where $\mathrm{Sym}^k(V)$ denotes the $k^\mathrm{th}$ symmetric power of $V$ and denote it $T_k$. Knowing $\det T$, is there a general formula for $\det T_k$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have that $\det T_k$ is a fixed (depending on $n=\dim V$ and $k$ only) power of
$\det T$. To see this, as well as getting the power, one can for instance note
that $\mathrm{SL}(V)$ is the commutator subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ (except for extremely small finite fields but we can always increase the size of the field) and hence
if $\det T=1$ then $\det T_k=1$. We can then write any $T\in\mathrm{GL}(V)$ in
the form $DS$, where $S\in\mathrm{SL}(V)$ and $D$ a diagonal matrix with
diagonal entries $(t,1,1,\ldots,1)$. Then $\det((DS)_k)=\det(D_k)\cdot1$ so it
suffices to compute $\det(D_k)$ but in the standard basis of $\mathrm{Sym}^kV$,
given a basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ of $V$, $D_k$ is a diagonal entries and its
determinant is $t^R$, where $R=\sum_{0\leq i\leq k}is^{n-1}_{k-i}$. Here
$s^{a}_{b}=\dim \mathrm{Sym}^bU$ where $\dim U=a$ which equals $\binom{a+b-1}{b}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please tell me where I can read about these things?

Comment: @Brian, try a text on multilinear algebra, for example "finite dimensional multilinear algebra" by M. Marcus discusses such topics in chapter 2.

Comment: More precisely,
$$\det T_k=(\det T)^N,\qquad N=C_{n-1}^{k-1}.$$
$N$ is a binomial coefficient.

Comment: Actually, a density argument would also work (assume that everything is diagonalizable).

Comment: There is a typo in Denis Serre's formula : one has $N=C_{n+k-1}^{n}$.